# Adblock is blocking subdomain links on my site

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, adblock

My domain is example.com and I have a link in my website `<a href="http://sub.example.com" target="_blank">subdomain</a>` When I click it a new tab is opened and closed immediately in Chrome/Firefox with Adblock installed. It works fine when I uninstall Adblock. Any way to work this thing around? Thanks

Comment: Provide the "real" link, because Adblock uses regex which may match your sub-domain link but not `http://sub.example.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `ads` part of your URL. Adblock's common filter lists block every URL with `ads`, `advert` and others in the domain part (like `ads.kida.al`) or the URL part (like `kida.al/ads/`).

You can look into the most used filter lists from easylist: https://easylist.to/

When you want to make Adblock's life hard then you've to use advertisement URLs that cannot be distinguished from your content URLs.

Comment: what if was the domain for an ad company and the website was a normal website,
then the website will also be blocked, there is no white list to compare with?

Comment: There is a whitelist but most users choose a blocking list like easylist and that's it. As far as I know AdblockPlus filters do not block entire sites but assets on the site. btw: My answer is 8 years old and maybe outdated.